# replace "\" character with gsub R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

Does anybody knows how can i replace "\" in r?

Other answers have posted something like:

```
l <- "1120190\neconomic"
gsub("\\", "", l, fixed=TRUE)
```

But didn't work in my case.

Comment: This is not a backslash, it's a newline character (`\n`). You can use `gsub("\n", "", l)` if you need to remove it.

Comment: I have reopened this question because it was edited and is now apparently not a duplicate of "replace a backslash". But I'm sure there's a duplicate for "replace a newline".

Comment: hello, can you use `cat` eg `cat(l)` do you see any backslash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\n` is a symbol for newline and if you want to replace it with space you can use the following:

```
l <- "1120190\neconomic"
cat(l)
gsub("\n", " ", l, fixed=TRUE)
```

Note, that the output would be:

```
1120190
economic
[1] "1120190 economic"
```

Comment: Didn't work :( I've editetd my post with one example